# How to Sort Record in Ruby on Rails based on Last Record Timestamp from References Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, orm, ruby-on-rails-6

I need to create a live chat app and now I have three models :

1. ChatRoom
2. ChatRoomMember
3. ChatRoomMessage

From this three models, I use *includes* and *references* to get the list of chat_rooms for current login user. Here is the code that I have wrote.

```
@chat_rooms = ChatRoom.includes(:members).references(:members)
@chat_rooms = @chat_rooms.includes(:messages).references(:messages)
@chat_rooms = @chat_rooms.where 'chat_room_members.user_id = ?', @current_user.id
@chat_rooms = @chat_rooms.order 'chat_room_messages.created_at DESC'
@chat_rooms = @chat_rooms.limit(limit).offset(offset)
```

However, the order didn't work as I expected. What I want is that the **chat_rooms** are sorted by *created_at* column from the last message in that room. How can I do this ?

Here is the database structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone has help me to solve this probel. I have my own answer. Here is it.

```
SELECT chat_rooms.*, (SELECT chat_room_messages.created_at FROM chat_room_messages WHERE chat_room_messages.chat_room_id = chat_rooms.id ORDER BY chat_room_messages.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_message_at FROM chat_rooms INNER JOIN chat_room_members ON chat_room_members.chat_room_id = chat_rooms.id WHERE chat_room_members.user_id = #{@current_user.id} ORDER BY last_message_at DESC
```

I use raw query for solve this problem. Hope this can help anyone who need it !

Answer (score 1):

Use association to avoid `where 'chat_room_members.user_id = ?', @current_user.id`

Here is my suggestion, assuming `User` has associations looking like:

```rb
class User
  has_many :chat_room_members
  has_many :chat_rooms, through: :chat_room_members
end
```

```rb
# list only rooms with at least on message
@chat_rooms = @current_user.chat_rooms.joins(:messages).order('chat_room_messages.created_at DESC').limit(limit).offset(offset)

# list all rooms even if there is no message attached
@chat_rooms = @current_user.chat_rooms.distinct.left_joins(:messages).order('chat_room_messages.created_at DESC').limit(limit).offset(offset)
```

Comment: It was fix the order position, but it has a bug when the room does not have any message, the room does not appear in the list.

Comment: I think the problem is come from `joins`, so I tried use `includes` and `references` but it doesn't fix the position problem

Comment: And if the room has 3 messages, it will return the chat_room in the list for three times

Comment: I've updated my answer.  `left_joins` includes room without message. I've added a `distinct` contraint as well, just in case. 

Comment: `includes` is for [eager loading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). I never use `references`.

Comment: End with `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ages"."chat_room_id" = "chat_rooms"."id" ORDER BY chat_room_...):`

Comment: Just remove `distinct`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: if remove `distinct`, this will return the same room record for multiple times. If the room has 3 messages, it will return the room for 3 times.

Comment: Ok. Can you add the result of the query with « distinct » and a « .to_sql » ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ChatRoom.includes(:messages).order('chat_room_messages.created_at DESC')
```

Comment: what is the difference between my code with yours ?